# Best way to replace single quotes to search against a database correctly?

Tags: php, sql, database, web-applications, validation

I'm working on an application where users are searched for by multiple different criteria. One of the available criteria is searching by name. Names are stored in the database with HTML characters stripped, eg. a ' is stored as `&#39;`. The problem with this is that if a user searches by name inputting the regular english name, it looks for the english name rather than the HTML-stripped name in the database. I have tried using htmlspecialchars`($string, ENT_QUOTES)`, but for some reason it won't always replace the single quote correctly. Can anyone think of why this would happen, or recommend a better way? Thank you!

Comment: Quotes should be escaped using the database vendor specific escape function.

Comment: `ENT_QUOTES` is a constant, it does not need the `$` prefix. That said, look at the code that does the `' -> &#39;` conversion and just reuse the same logic in your code. And hope that conversion was, is, and will be consistent.

Comment: I still cannot get this to work. `htmlentities_decode($string)` won't even work to decode `&#39;` back to a single apostrophe. Could character encoding be affecting this in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using this `html_entity_decode($string)` instead of `htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES);`

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to replace single quotes. All you need to do is to use either **[`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)** or `MySQLi` extension. Example of PDO,

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE name = :name');

$stmt->execute(array(':name' => $name));
foreach ($stmt as $row) 
{
    // do something with $row
}
```

In that way, it allows you to search even if the value has single quote.

Comment: @user1631077 [More Examples Here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score 0):

both ans are good but you can also try this...

```
 function change_text($in, $out, $text){

$input = array($in);
$change = array($out) ;
$result = @str_replace ($input ,$change, $text);
return $result;
}

$change_text = change_text("'", '',$text);
```

hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

on your query, replace your ' (quote) to ''. first quote will sign that caracter after this quote will be use as is.

bellow sample code:

```
mysql> select * from activities where activity='aku''kamu';
+----+----------+---------+
| id | activity | user_id |
+----+----------+---------+
|  1 | aku'kamu |       3 |
+----+----------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> update activities set activity='aku''kamu' where id=2
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from activities where activity='aku''kamu';
+----+----------+---------+
| id | activity | user_id |
+----+----------+---------+
|  1 | aku'kamu |       3 |
|  2 | aku'kamu |       3 |
+----+----------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```